# How to pass Func to a class which encapsulates the Expression based on that Func?

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-expressions

I have class `DropdownFilter` which has:

```
private readonly Func<TEntity, string> fieldWhichMustEqualValue;

public override IQueryable<TEntity> Filter(IQueryable<TEntity> filteredEntityCollection, string value)
{
    return filteredEntityCollection.Where(entity => this.fieldWhichMustEqualValue(entity) == value);
}
```

I use it as:

```
IQueryable<Invoice> entityCollectionToFilterAndOrder = ...

var dropdownFilter = new DropdownFilter<Invoice>(invoice => invoice.SomeProperty);
entityCollectionToFilterAndOrder = dropdownFilter.Filter(entityCollectionToFilterAndOrder, "bla bla bla");
```

which gives me

> The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities.

I understand the issue is that I am essentially asking for SQL equivalent of `Invoke`, which of course is wrong.

How should I rewrite the code? I understand that it needs to be an expression. My goal is the consumer of the `DropDownFilter` to just specify a property of `TEntity`, without providing the expression. i.e. the expression has to be encapsulated into the filter.

I have tried:

```
Expression<Func<TEntity, string>> expr = mc => this.fieldWhichMustEqualValue(mc);
Expression le = Expression.Equal(expr.Body, Expression.Constant(value));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(le, expr.Parameters);
return filteredEntityCollection.Where(lambda);
```

but it basically gives me the same result.

Comment: You're telling EF to translate "call this arbitrary method I have in my C# code" into SQL.  How do you expect it to do that?  It has no way of knowing what that method is, what it does, or what SQL could possibly be equivalent to it.

Comment: This is why I want to convert it into an expression. Why wouldn't I be able to do that? If I can pass the expression from the outside, why wouldn't I be able to create the expression on the inside, and from the outside only pass part of it (the property)? This is the question I have posted.

Comment: How *would* you do it?  How could you possibly convert some arbitrary C# function into SQL?  If you pass the expression in from the outside then you're not converting some arbitrary C# method into SQL, you're converting an `Expression` to SQL, and that expression contains all of the information needed to generate the SQL query.

Comment: OK, instead of a function, is there any way I can pass the `XXX` in `return filteredEntityCollection.Where(entity => XXX == value);` as a parameter? Where XXX is a property of `entity`.

Comment: If you have an expression, you can use the code you already have to create a new expression that transforms a property mapping into an equality check.  But you have to start with a valid expression to do that.

Comment: I will be eternally grateful if you illustrate your last comment with an example. I have already moved to a `Expression<Func<TEntity, string>> fieldWhichMustEqualValue` parameter, but still can't get it to work.

Comment: It's quite simple.  If it was ever a `Func`, then you've lost, you're done, you've got no shot at converting it into SQL.  You need to only ever have `Expression` instances, from start to finish.  It won't guarantee that it'll work, but it'll at least have a shot.

Answer (score 0):

`Func<TEntity, string>` is a C# function so that cannot possibly be executed in the SQL server. However, if you change that to an expression, it could work:

```
private readonly Expression<Func<TEntity, string>> fieldWhichMustEqualValue;
```

However, now the `Filter` function would not compile since you can't invoke expressions. What you need to do is to compose a new expression:

```
public static UnaryExpression WrapInPropertyAccess(this ConstantExpression constant) {
    Tuple<object> container = new Tuple<object>(constant.Value);
    Expression containerExpression = Expression.Constant(container, typeof(Tuple<object>));
    MemberExpression propAccess = Expression.Property(containerExpression, "Item1");
    UnaryExpression result = Expression.Convert(propAccess, constant.Type); // Cast back the object to the value type
    return result;
}

private Expression<TEntity, bool> FieldEqualsValue(string value) {
    var comparison = Expression.Equal(fieldWhichMustEqualValue.Body, Expression.Constant(value).WrapInPropertyAccess());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(comparison, fieldWhichMustEqualValue.Parameters);
}

public override IQueryable<TEntity> Filter(IQueryable<TEntity> filteredEntityCollection, string value)
{
    var condition = FieldEqualsValue(value);
    return filteredEntityCollection.Where(condition);
}
```

The `WrapInPropertyAccess` function is not strictly needed, but using it makes Entity Framework generate a parameterized expression.